# Authorization Header - Javascript Vuejs

Tags: vuejs2, basic-authentication, vue-resource

I have a backend that performs BASIC authentication. I am passing the username/password encoded in curl as follows

```
curl -D- -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic cmFtcmFtOnBhc3N3b3Jk" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http://localhost:9000/users/login"
```

and It works fine

Whereas in vue.js using vue-resource I am trying to do the same using

```
 var options = {
        url: 'http://localhost:9000/users/login',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: 
        { 
            'Authorization': 'Basic cmFtcmFtOnBhc3N3b3Jk'
        }
    }
    context.$http(options).then(res => {
      if (res.ok) {
        cb({ authenticated: true })
      } else {
        cb({ authenticated: false })
      }
    })
```

But it is not getting authenticated. The request information i got from devtools is as follows

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-GB,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.4
Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
DNT:1
Host:localhost:9000
Origin:http://evil.com/
Referer:http://localhost:8080/Login
```

I do not see the authorization information being passed to the server. Am i doing something wrong ? Note : Both server and client are on localhost.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`vue-resource` is [retired](https://medium.com/the-vue-point/retiring-vue-resource-871a82880af4) so I don't think you should use it anymore. Instead, how about you use `fetch` instead as suggested and see if it works:

```
fetch('http://localhost:9000/users/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: new Headers({
        'Authorization: Basic cmFtcmFtOnBhc3N3b3Jk',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }),
    body: JSON.stringify(req.body.payload)
})
```